# CPU Features.GetCount return incorrect number for CPU Cores

Tags: nsis, cpu-cores

I'm using CPU Features plug-in to get CPU core and this is the code:

```
${CPUFeatures.GetCount} $CPUCore
```

Apparently, there is a computer with 12 CPU Cores and the $CPUCore shows only 1 core. I think maybe there is a possibility that the $CPUCore only return the first digit, but how can I know it for sure?

Or, is there any other way to get the CPU Core numbers?

Comment: I doubt it just returns the first digit, it is more likely a problem with the CPU detection code...

Comment: I just browsed through the source code however nothing sticks out. The plugin uses classes from the x264 project (Feb. 2013) however the limit in the 2011 version was already 64 CPUs: https://mailman.videolan.org/pipermail/x264-devel/2011-January/008181.html

Comment: Can you give us more information? What platform (Win, Linux, MACOS,...?), What exact CPU do you have (Intel, AMD, ...) and what is the exact name of the CPU (Opteron 6338P, Xeon E5-2697,...)?

Comment: @Lonzak the platform is Win7 and the CPU is Intel. When I check the computer specification, it says 6 Core(s) and 12 Logical Processors. Apparently CPUFeatures.GetCount will return the logical processors number and not the core.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why the plugin is failing but you could ask Windows with something like this:

```
!include LogicLib.nsh
!ifndef ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER
!define ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER 122
!endif
!define RelationProcessorCore 0

!if "${NSIS_PTR_SIZE}" <= 4
Function GetProcessorPhysCoreCount
System::Store S
StrCpy $9 0 ; 0 if we fail
System::Call 'kernel32::GetLogicalProcessorInformationEx(i${RelationProcessorCore},i,*i0r2)i.r0?e'
Pop $3
${If} $3 = ${ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER}
${AndIf} $2 <> 0
    System::Alloc $2
    System::Call 'kernel32::GetLogicalProcessorInformationEx(i${RelationProcessorCore},isr1,*ir2r2)i.r0'
    Push $1
    ${If} $0 <> 0
    loop_7:
        IntOp $9 $9 + 1
        System::Call *$1(i,i.r3)
        IntOp $1 $1 + $3
        IntOp $2 $2 - $3
        IntCmp $2 0 "" loop_7 loop_7
    ${EndIf}
    Pop $1
    System::Free $1
${Else}
    System::Call 'kernel32::GetLogicalProcessorInformation(i,*i0r2)i.r0?e'
    Pop $3
    ${If} $3 = ${ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER}
        System::Alloc $2
        System::Call 'kernel32::GetLogicalProcessorInformation(isr1,*ir2r2)i.r0'
        Push $1
        ${If} $0 <> 0
        loop_v:
            System::Call *$1(i,i.r3)
            ${If} $3 = ${RelationProcessorCore}
                IntOp $9 $9 + 1
            ${EndIf}
            IntOp $1 $1 + 24
            IntOp $2 $2 - 24
            IntCmp $2 0 "" loop_v loop_v
        ${EndIf}
        Pop $1
        System::Free $1
    ${EndIf}
${EndIf}
Push $9
System::Store L
FunctionEnd

Function CountSetBits32
Exch $0
Push $1
Push $2
Push $3
StrCpy $3 0
StrCpy $1 0
loop:
    IntOp $2 1 << $1
    IntOp $2 $2 & $0
    ${IfThen} $2 <> 0 ${|} IntOp $3 $3 + 1 ${|}
    IntOp $1 $1 + 1
    StrCmp $1 32 "" loop
StrCpy $0 $3
Pop $3
Pop $2
Pop $1
Exch $0
FunctionEnd

Function GetProcessorLogicalCoreCount
System::Store S
StrCpy $9 0 ; 0 if we fail
System::Call 'kernel32::GetLogicalProcessorInformationEx(i${RelationProcessorCore},i,*i0r2)i.r0?e'
Pop $3
${If} $3 = ${ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER}
${AndIf} $2 <> 0
    System::Alloc $2
    System::Call 'kernel32::GetLogicalProcessorInformationEx(i${RelationProcessorCore},isr1,*ir2r2)i.r0'
    Push $1
    ${If} $0 <> 0
    loop_7:
        System::Call *$1(i,i.r3,&i22,&i2,i.r5)
        Push $5
        Call CountSetBits32
        Pop $5
        IntOp $9 $9 + $5
        IntOp $1 $1 + $3
        IntOp $2 $2 - $3
        IntCmp $2 0 "" loop_7 loop_7
    ${EndIf}
    Pop $1
    System::Free $1
${Else}
    System::Call 'kernel32::GetLogicalProcessorInformation(i,*i0r2)i.r0?e'
    Pop $3
    ${If} $3 = ${ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER}
        System::Alloc $2
        System::Call 'kernel32::GetLogicalProcessorInformation(isr1,*ir2r2)i.r0'
        Push $1
        ${If} $0 <> 0
        loop_v:
            System::Call *$1(i,i.r3)
            ${If} $3 = ${RelationProcessorCore}
                System::Call *$1(i.r3)
                Push $3
                Call CountSetBits32
                Pop $3
                IntOp $9 $9 + $3
            ${EndIf}
            IntOp $1 $1 + 24
            IntOp $2 $2 - 24
            IntCmp $2 0 "" loop_v loop_v
        ${EndIf}
        Pop $1
        System::Free $1
    ${EndIf}
${EndIf}
Push $9
System::Store L
FunctionEnd
!endif

Section
Call GetProcessorPhysCoreCount
Pop $0
Call GetProcessorLogicalCoreCount
Pop $1
DetailPrint PhysCores=$0,LogicalCores=$1
SectionEnd
```

You should still use ${CPUFeatures.GetCount} as a fallback because GetLogicalProcessorInformation[Ex] does not exist on all versions of Windows...

Comment: apparently ${CPUFeatures.GetCount} return the logical processor numbers not the processor cores so I don't use it anymore.

Comment: the application is limited to Win7 and 8 only

Answer (score 0):

I try to use the code from this [forum](http://forums.winamp.com/showthread.php?t=321596) and modified it a little bit so I only get the processor core numbers:

```
!include "LogicLib.nsh" 

!define ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER 122 

; Size of SYSTEM_LOGICAL_PROCESSOR_INFORMATION on 32-bit systems 
!define SYS_LOG_PROC_INFO_SIZE    24 
; Offset of Relationship in the SYSTEM_LOGICAL_PROCESSOR_INFORMATION structure 
!define RELATIONSHIP_OFFSET       4 
; Enum value of Relationship identifying Processor Core 
!define RELATIONPROCESSORCORE     0 

; Count the number of bits set in given value 
; Parameters: value 
; Returns: number of bits set in given value 
Function countbits 
   Exch $0 
   Push $1 
   Push $2 

   ; Set initial value for number of bits set in $0 
   StrCpy $1 0 

   ${While} $0 > 0 
      ; Clear least significant bit set 
      IntOp $2 $0 - 1 
      IntOp $0 $0 & $2 
      ; Increment number of bits set 
      IntOp $1 $1 + 1 
   ${EndWhile} 

   ; Return number of bits set 
   StrCpy $0 $1 

   Pop $2 
   Pop $1 
   Exch $0 
FunctionEnd 

; Evaluate processor information 
; Paramaters: buffer, length 
; Returns: number of cores 
Function evalcpuinfo 
   Exch $0 ; length 
   Exch 
   Exch $1 ; buffer 
   Push $2 
   Push $3 
   Push $4 
   Push $5 ; Processor Cores 
   Push $6 ; Logical Processors 

   ; Set buffer offset at the end of the buffer 
   StrCpy $2 $0 

   ; Initialize number of Processor Cores and Logical Processors 
   StrCpy $5 0 
   StrCpy $6 0 

   ; Iterate through buffer starting from end 
   ${While} $2 >= ${SYS_LOG_PROC_INFO_SIZE} 
       ; Calculate start address of an element 
       IntOp $2 $2 - ${SYS_LOG_PROC_INFO_SIZE} 
       IntOp $3 $1 + $2 
       ; Get ProcessorMask value from element 
       System::Call "*$3(i.r4)" 
       Push $4 
       IntOp $3 $3 + ${RELATIONSHIP_OFFSET} 
       ; Get Relationship value from element 
       System::Call "*$3(i.r4)" 
       ${If} $4 == ${RELATIONPROCESSORCORE} 
           ; Increment Processor cores 
           IntOp $5 $5 + 1 
           ; Determine number of Logical Processor by counting the bits 
           ; set in the value of ProcessorMask 
           Call countbits 
           Pop $4 
           ; Sum up Logical Processors 
           IntOp $6 $6 + $4 
       ${Else} 
           Pop $4 
       ${EndIf} 
   ${EndWhile} 

   ; Set processor information as return value 
   StrCpy $0 $5

   Pop $6 
   Pop $5 
   Pop $4 
   Pop $3 
   Pop $2 
   Pop $1 
   Exch $0 
FunctionEnd 

; Get processor information 
; Returns: number of Processor Cores and Logical Processors 
Function getcpuinfo 
  Push $0 
  Push $1 
  Push $2 
  Push $3 
  Push $4 

  ; GetLogicalProcessorInformation is only available on  
  ; Windows XP SP3 or its successors. 

  ; Initialize buffer and its length 
  StrCpy $1 0 
  StrCpy $2 0 

  ; Determine required length of buffer 
  System::Call "kernel32::GetLogicalProcessorInformation(ir1, *ir2r2) i.r3 ? e" 
  Pop $4 
  ${If} $3 == 0 
     ${If} $4 == ${ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER} 
         ; Allocate buffer 
         System::Alloc $2 
         Pop $1 
         ${If} $1 != 0 
             ; Get processor information 
             System::Call "kernel32::GetLogicalProcessorInformation(ir1, *ir2r2) i.r3 ? e" 
             Pop $4 
             ${If} $3 != 1 
                 StrCpy $0 "Error: $4" 
             ${Else} 
                 Push $1 ; buffer 
                 Push $2 ; length 
                 Call evalcpuinfo 
                 Pop $0 
             ${EndIf} 
             ; Deallocate buffer 
             System::Free $1 
         ${Else} 
             StrCpy $0 "Error: memory allocation failed!" 
         ${EndIf} 
     ${Else} 
         StrCpy $0 "Error: $4" 
     ${EndIf} 
  ${Else} 
     StrCpy $0 "GetLogicalProcessorInformation is not available on your system!" 
  ${EndIf} 

  Pop $4 
  Pop $3 
  Pop $2 
  Pop $1 
  Exch $0 
FunctionEnd
```

I think the code is quite similar with Anders code. I have tried it in three different PCs and get the correct numbers for processor core.

Comment: Why did you choose this over my answer? I'm using both GetLogicalProcessorInformation and GetLogicalProcessorInformationEx while your code is limited to 64 cores...

Comment: Why do I need to use GetLogicalProcessorInformationEx also while using GetLogicalProcessorInformation is enough?

Comment: The MSDN page for GetLogicalProcessorInformation: "On systems with more than 64 logical processors, the GetLogicalProcessorInformation function retrieves logical processor information about processors in the processor group to which the calling thread is currently assigned. Use the GetLogicalProcessorInformationEx function to retrieve information about processors in all processor groups on the system."